# How to insert video file in database using hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, video, pojo

Hello programmers of around the world i have a problem when i trying to insert a video file in my mysql database using hibernate, and i hope find a solution here.

I have this pojo to map database table.

```
@Entity
```

public class Client implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String dni;
private String nom;
private Date neix;
@Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB") 
private byte[] image;

public Client() {
}

public Client(String dni, String nom, Date neix, byte[] image) {
    this.dni = dni;
    this.nom = nom;
    this.neix = neix;
    this.image = image;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}

public void setDni(String dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public Date getNeix() {
    return neix;
}

public void setNeix(Date neix) {
    this.neix = neix;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Client{" + "id=" + id + ", dni=" + dni + ", nom=" + nom + ", neix=" + neix + ", image=" + image + '}';
}
```

And this is my main to save client into my database, i tried this with images, and it works, but it fails with video files.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
    Service s = new Service();

    Client c1 = new Client();
    c1.setDni("123412");
    c1.setNeix(new Date("2003/11/24"));
    c1.setNom("SNK");
    c1.setImage(readBytesFromFile("C:\\Users\\Adrikus\\Documents\\Mipony\\snk2x1.mp4"));
    s.addClient(c1);
}

private static byte[] readBytesFromFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File inputFile = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
    inputStream.read(fileBytes);
    inputStream.close();

    return fileBytes;
}
```

And this is error message throw it by hibernate:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.<init>(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:77)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBytes(PreparedStatement.java:3407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBytes(PreparedStatement.java:3382)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:62)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:282)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2818)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3025)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3556)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
at Dao.AccountDao.saveClient(AccountDao.java:49)
```

Thanking you in advance for trying to help me :)

Comment: If mysql's driver creates another byte array/buffer to store your byte array, that would double your heap requirements. Try increasing the jvm heap size with -Xmx. If this works let me know I will post it as an answer

Comment: Your approach only works for relatively small files. Video files are usually large. Reading all the bytes into memory will eventually exceed heap size no matter how large you set it. Besides, storing large binary objects in a database is inefficient. I suggest you keep your files on disk an just store the file path in the database.

Comment: @efekctive this solution doesnt work i augmented memory of jvm using -Xmx4G and program throws the same error, but thank you for the try

Comment: it is was an easy/cheap one to try. You are better off with the previous comment. Keep the movies on disk and store the path. You may need to put in place some protections(if the file is deleted from disk the data is corrupted because the path is meaningless) but makes more sense